# how to get the array of object in react native

Tags: react-native

Hereby attached my data

```js
{
  pageOfItems: [
    {
      __v: 0,
      _id: "5f10121efb43a43e30a4fbd2",
      brand: [Object],
      category: [Object],
      color: [Array],
      createdAt: "2020-07-16T08:38:37.787Z",
      description: "Full Sleeves, Na, Na",
      discountType: "Percentage",
      discountValue: 50.07153075822603,
      fabric: null,
      gender: [Object],
      itemcode: "MW4405",
      name: "Moda Grey Casual Shirts",
      photo: [Array],
      price: 699,
      quantity: 10,
      rotation: 0,
      shipping: true,
      size: [Array],
      sleeves: "5f0ffa443c7e14330408c285",
      sold: 0,
      status: "ON",
      store: "5f10119dbfe6ec3e38b0a71b",
      subcategory: "5f04732469c00914e0bb905c",
      updatedAt: "2020-07-16T08:38:37.787Z",
    },
  ],
};
```

how to get in flatlist in please tell me

Comment: Here https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

Comment: Play around with that example

Comment: i know have to use the flat list but how to get the value from with array of objects

Comment: What value? see [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const obj = {
  pageOfItems: [...],
};


<FlatList
  data={obj.pageOfItems}
  renderItem={({ item, index}) => (
    <View>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
  keyExtractor={(item,index) => index.toString()}
/>
```

Comment: the value i store in state how to get it

Comment: which value you wanted to get?